# How does only not appear Year when I use datetime.strptime?

Tags: python

I have a str 'Jan 22 16:47:37',I want to convert it to time type.

```
datetime.strptime('Jan 22 16:47:37', "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
```

I get

```
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 22, 16, 47, 37)
```

I hope the result of the code is datetime.datetime( 1, 22, 16, 47, 37)

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: do you need the result to be a datetime object?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
value=datetime.strptime('Jan 22 16:47:37', "%b %d %H:%M:%S")

(value.month,value.day,value.hour,value.minute,value.second)
```

You can't get a datetime object without the year. Refer to the definition of datetime object

```
?datetime

Docstring:
datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])

The year, month and day arguments are required. tzinfo may be None, or an
instance of a tzinfo subclass. The remaining arguments may be ints or longs.
Type:      type
```